# EXCHANGE and MAPI : domain admins not allowed

Tags: active-directory, exchange, administrative-privileges

I can't configure Outlook 2013 with Exchange 2016 as domain admin, it asks me for password, i nter it and reask as well.
No problem with users, only with Administrators (Builtin, domain admins...)

Is it a normal behavior?
Is it possible to bypass this issue? If yes, How? is it secure to let admins have a mailbox?

Thank you.

Comment: Admin accounts have no need for a mailbox.  This behavior is partially by design, or a byproduct of a design.

Comment: Agree with what Semicolon has replied above, here are some discussions on the issue in the similar thread for your reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d69c74b-a7ac-4a85-8475-9bd94158a17c/outlook-prompting-for-passwords-after-moving-to-exchange-online?forum=exchangesvradmin